# Why is my CHOICE program not working?

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a Windows Batch program, and have the following:

```
choice /c "12" /n /t 10 /d 1 /m "> "
if %errorlevel%=="255" goto start
if %errorlevel%=="2" goto choice2
if %errorlevel%=="1" goto choice1
if %errorlevel%=="0" goto start

:choice1
echo choice1
goto eof

:choice2
echo choice2
goto eof

:eof
```

When I run it, I pick choice two by hitting "2" on my keyboard, and `%ERRORLEVEL%` does say that I picked "2". However, when it comes to the IF statements, it always seems to say "choice1". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. `errorlevel` can get reset. When you have a long sequence of code inspecting a return value, it's best to assign `%errorlevel%` to some other variable and inspect that instead.
2. As @NielsPeeren mentions, you should be consistent with quoting - either quote both sides of the expression, or neither.

Try this:

```
choice /c "12" /n /t 10 /d 1 /m "> "
set response=%errorlevel%
if "%response%"=="255" goto start
if "%response%"=="2" goto choice2
if "%response%"=="1" goto choice1
if "%response%"=="0" goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking it to be equal to a value you should remove the ""